# Why did Captain America freeze?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, captain-america-the-first-avenger

The plane crashed in the Arctic, but surely that’s not enough to cause an instant freezing, whether it lands on the ground or on the water. It’s much more likely he would have survived the crash and then either slowly died due to cold or drowned.

I understand for the drama effect (and to be able to bring him back) it was needed to happen for plot reasons, but has there been any attempt on explaining how it actually happened (e.g. side effect of the tesseract or something)?

Comment: I'm not sure but this almost sounds like a real science question, although I didn't watch the movie, so I don't know how much his freezing differs from in the comics or animated series and such.

Comment: I won't put it as an answer because I don't know what to quote, but he went into suspended animation because of his altered metabolism, which was due to the super soldier serum. It definitely wasn't a side effect of having been around the tesseract. In the original version of this happening in the comics, IIRC, he drove off a pier on a motorcycle into icy-cold water. In that case, he didn't drown either.

Comment: Because it was very cold

Comment: He's just like T'Challa, they both freeze.

Comment: Who said it was instant freezing? It wouldn't be particularly surprising if Cap was unconscious for some time after a plane crash like that.

Answer (score 2):

There are still "preserved mammoths" underneath permafrost in icy cold regions of the Northern Hemisphere. The Super Soldier Serum made it possible for Captain America to be reanimated, rather quickly, once his body was thawed out decades after his plane crashed in the Northern Atlantic.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 "Obviously" the Super Solider Serum made it possible for Cap to reanimate rather quickly after thawing out, because no ordinary cryogenically frozen human can recover from being frozen the way that Cap did. Walt Disney and Ted Williams are cryogenically frozen. If they were thawed out today, they'd remain dead. They don't have the Super Soldier Serum.